# Magento 2: Image not uploading in UI form "Attention: File was not uploaded”

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, image-upload, ui-form, image-preview

I have created a custom form using Ui_Component,facing problem during image upload. I am using 2 column left layout ie, tab structure.

https://prnt.sc/nouwe5

When I try to upload the image it shows an  alert "Attention: File was not uploaded".

https://prnt.sc/nouwwm

The file upload is working fine when I use 1 column layout.
Here is the ui component

```
<field name="image_path">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image_path</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="visibleValue" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="example/example/imageupload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

I have found a related bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15675

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Can you please add your xml code for file uploading field ?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra I have added the code

Comment: <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item> change this line with below line  <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">imageUploader</item> and try

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Still the same error